# How to recover from a leak

Tags: repair, water, flooring, leak

I have had a leak in my flat. It came from my ceiling (from the upstairs neighbours), and went down my wooden floor. It was not gushing, but dripping for about two days.

The surveyor came and with his tools said that there was water below the wooden floor (engineered floor). That probably went down the underlay and underfloor (it is concrete beneath, I am ground floor).

His solution is to remove the wooden floor, underlay and underfloor from the affected area, let it dry for three weeks with machines, and then install a new wooden floor.

This is costly and disruptive as me and my family will have to find a new accomodation for about a month.
Is there a better/easier solution? Can we remove the water/moisture without removing the wooden floor?

Comment: Nope. It'll mold, cause swelling, and start to decay long before you get things dried out. I dispute that you'd need to leave, though. I spent most of my youth living in remodel projects. It just takes a little planning and patience.

Comment: I agree with isherwood many homes I lived in were remodels as a kid and as an adult. You could live there while the repairs are done. It really needs to be dried out or there will be lots more damage and possible health issues in the future.+

Comment: Are the landlord and insurance going to cover all your costs? If they are paying for it then spend a month at a hotel and enjoy yourself.